# Deleting certain strings in a DataFrame column (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
  Column 1  Column 2
0    A B C        34
1    D E F        42
2    G H I        42
```

I want to delete certain strings from (not all strings) from the Column 1.
The result I expect:

```
  Column 1  Column 2
0        C        34
1        F        42
2        I        42
```

Any solutions will be accepted.

---

Comment: If you just want to keep the last character: `df['Column 1].str[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the last non space part with a regex:

```
df['Column 1'] = df['Column 1'].str.extract(r'(\S+$)')
```

Or [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on spaces and get the last item with the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
df['Column 1'] = df['Column 1'].str.split(r'\s+').str[-1]
```

output:

```
  Column 1  Column 2
0        C        34
1        F        42
2        I        42
```

###### deletion approach

Because you asked for "deleting" a part of the string, the approach would be to use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Column 1'] = df['Column 1'].str.replace(r'.*\s+', '', regex=True)
```

although probably not the best suited one here.